# Selenium RC - Element Link not found (Only in Internet Explorer)

Tags: internet-explorer, automated-tests, element, selenium-rc

I am currently having a bit of a nightmare getting IE8, 9 and 10 to automate with Selenium RC properly. The issue is that it cannot seem to find anything of type link=whatever. I get an error 'Element link=Live Dead Assay not found' in the testrunner. It fails on the line:

```
try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("link=Live Dead Assay"))
```

The thing is that all of the other browsers we test on (Firefox, Chrome and Safari) all work without a hitch. Only IE with the problem.

Below is the script that we use (this was created by exporting from Selenium IDE).

Just to let you all know, I have tried placing pauses in front of the selenium.isElementPresent line and this doesn't work. I've also tried slowing the test runner down to the slowest speed, again without success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

### Chris

```
    @Test
public void clickLink() throws Exception {
    // Open nav and expand Screens
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("css=#browse_screens_folder_52 > ins.jstree-icon")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    selenium.click("css=#browse_screens_folder_52 > ins.jstree-icon");
    // Open small image (Live Dead Assay)
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("css=#browse_screen_568 > ins.jstree-icon")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    selenium.click("css=#browse_screen_568 > ins.jstree-icon");
    // 35669 Check info table present
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("link=Live Dead Assay")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    selenium.click("link=Live Dead Assay");

    }
```

---

30/1/13
I should add that we are also running a html script via Jenkins and this also fails at the same point. We have *iexplore set for this.

However, just today, on a colleague's local machine we ran htmlsuite Selenium Standalone Server from the command line. In this case we used *piiexplore, and the tests actually found the element that the other setups failed on. I have since tried *piiexplore with our Jenkins job but this did not work and failed at the same point as before.
Could this be a local machine setting? Or an issue with running tests through Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using xpath instead of link=blah. IE likes this :-)